# LoadLibrary in separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, dll, loadlibrary

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and C++, and loading a DLL at runtime. However, this blocks the user-experience. I was hoping to avoid this by pushing it off to a new thread (CreateThread), but it still blocks the UI thread.

Why?

Dustin

Comment: `LoadLibrary()` cannot be _that_ slow as to block UI. You should explain more on how you are doing it

Comment: Loading a DLL is a process-wide operation, the calling thread does not matter. If the performance hit comes from a bloated `DllMain()`, I'm afraid there's not much you can do.

Comment: Probably you should load the DLL at the beginning of your program so that it won't bother user experience too much. But of course you may want to check who it's taking so much time when loading it. E.g. allocate too much memory to cause the system swapping?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Some parts are process-wide, e.g. the loader-lock, but that does not affect performance. The `DllMain` part does affect performance but is not process-wide (runs on one thread only, which is why the calling thread **does** matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a guess, the DLL is doing things in its `DllMain` which are disallowed in that context. There is very little allowed, as it runs under loader lock.

Comment: But why would it block the UI?

Comment: @usr: Because Microsoft hasn't designed Windows under the assumption that you break the rules. I can't predict how Windows works internally, I just know that Bad Things can happen when you try too much in `DllMain`

Comment: This, and the corroborating comments above, were exactly it. A large amount of logic was in the DllMain of the loaded DLL. I fixed it by moving that logic to an exported call that is subsequently called after the LoadLibrary(). I did -not- know about the process lock. Thanks, all.